# Postgres Access Roles

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I'm trying to get my head around postgres roles.

I want to create a database and have the owner role have all privileges on the database.

I then want another role which cannot create tables but able to read/write from any tables that may be added to the db in the future.

I have done `REVOKE ALL ON schema public FROM public` and then `GRANT ALL ON schema public TO admin_role` and the admin role works.

But I can't figure out how to create a limited role with the create table permission revoked and it still able to see and read to tables within the database. If I do the `GRANT ALL ON schema public` it has all privileges which I don't want.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `GRANT` only on a schema. You can get more specific and `GRANT` specifically to a table, like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE xyz.items TO admin_role;
```

but note that `GRANT ALL` and `REVOKE ALL` are very large sledgehammers for building very small spice racks.

Consider reviewing the [excellent `GRANT` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) which covers this in detail.

For your specific case, you could do something as simple as:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM admin_role;
```

which would remove the right to create new objects in the schema.